# get the values from another class or object in java

Tags: java, oop, object

when i print the value of sentiment it gives me this value why?
 Sentiment@1540e19d
Sentiment@677327b6

```
public class Sentiment extends  Sample{
    public String value;

    public Sentiment(String val){

      value = val;

    }
}

in main class
 Sentiment positive = new Sentiment("+");
        Sentiment negative = new Sentiment("-");

        System.out.println(positive);
        System.out.println(negative);
```

Comment: override the toString method in your Sentiment class and write it to output what youd like it to

Answer (score 1):

Because the default `toString()` behaviour is to print class name and hashcode for the class.

Override `toString()` in your class to get better print friendly results

ex:

```
public class Sentiment extends  Sample{
    public String value;

    public Sentiment(String val){

      value = val;

    }
      @Override
     public String toString(){
     return "Value =  " +value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should either do

```
System.out.println(positive.value);
```

or

define `toString()` in Sentiment class

```
public class Sentiment extends  Sample{
    public String value;

    public Sentiment(String val){

      value = val;

    }

public String toString(){

return ""+value;

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you try to write to stdout, Java will automatically call the toString() method. When an object doesn't explicitly have a toString() method, it reverts to the Object class which has the method.

Object.java:toString()

```
 getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```